# Why Intellisense does not work for map<int, T *>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am surprised, by following behaviour of intellisense, why:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    std::map<int , int *> map;
    std::map<int , T *> map2;
    std::vector<int *> vec;
    std::vector<T *> vec2;

    T * doBar(void)
    {
        map./*displays everything*/
    --->map2./*displays only 4 members: at, swap and two operators*/   
        vec./*displays everything*/   
        vec2./*displays everything*/       
        return null;
    }
};
```

is this a bug? Or there is some particular reason behind showing only 4 members when the second is T/T*? Logic would tell me there is no reason to hide methods like `find` or `erase` for any types even when they are templated `second`s.  
Compiling code with not-displayed functions does not throw any errors and appears to work correctly. I am using Visual Studio 2012. *(and already deleted intellisense database several times)*
*EDIT: it indeed appears to be VS2012 specific bug, just confirmed it works in with VS2013*

Comment: Works fine in VS2013.  Let's call it a 2012 specific bug.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for this info (that answered is pretty much), should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably that `std::map<int , T *>` is an unknown type here. There might be a specialization. And from personal experience, specializations tend to confuse Intellisense.

Comment: Well, even though the type is unknown, should be guaranteed to find-able and etc., that's what generic containers are for, isn't it?

Comment: @wondra: The Intellisense compiler implements the core language, it doesn't know about the libraries.